# xpath to select nodes excluding by attribute value list

Tags: xml, xpath, contains, xmlnodelist

I would like to know if there is shorter approach to selecting a list of nodes ignoring the ones that have an attribute value specified in a list

Working example:

```
/item[not(@uid='id1') and not(@uid='id2')]
```

Desired alternative:

```
/item[not(@uid in('id1','id2'))]
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can either use regex - if your xpath implementation supports it - or write

```
/item[not(@uid='id1' or @uid='id2')]
```

which might be a bit shorter.

Comment: You were right, the other method if i had two items like 'id1' and 'id11' it would ignore both by error

Answer (score 8):

**If the list of attribute names is very long, the following is a good way to handle this situation**:

```
//item[not(contains('|attr1|attr2|attr3|attr4|attr5|attr6|attrN|', 
                    concat('|', @uid, '|')
                    )
           )]
```

Comment: I needed to build very long XPath in .NET.
Instead of using stuff like LINQ Aggregate method with seed, you can just simply join strings with '|', add trailing and leading, and use it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like this??

```
/item[not(contains('id1 id2', @uid))]
```

Comment: works, but risky for changes, as `contains(x, y)` is true for  non-existing y.

Comment: @Arne This one is the shortest but in what cases would it fail? The attribute we use to filter is a unique id without spaces

Answer (score 0):

At least in Xpath 2 general comparisons on sequences are performed pairwise and existentially, so you can write:

```
/item[not(@uid = ('id1','id2'))]
```